Should large data be localized in DynamicModule, and why does wrapping Module around it cause syntax warnings?
Apologies for the long question.  The question is more pedagogical than practical.
I am trying to improve the performance and usability of a simulation and its visualization.  The root of the question is whether a large set of data that is changing dynamically should be localized in DynamicModule or not.
Below, I give a list of 4 methods that illustrate the question. The final method appears to be working satisfactorily, but there is a syntax warning that I don't understand, and hoping that someone can explain it to me--and suggest a better way to achieve the same end.
The computation to update the data can be expensive.  The data is used to create a dynamic graphic.
I've constructed a simpler proxy problem to explain what I am asking. (However, in my actual application, the time for creation of the
graphic is constant. In the proxy problem, it is not constant.  My actual problem doesn't involve random walks. This question is about DynamicModule and its localized variables)
Proxy problem: Visualize the evolution of random walk paths of a "large" number of walkers.
This function takes a list and adds a random step to it. Nesting this would give a random walk in 2D:
grow[positions_List, stepSize_] := Join[positions, {Last[positions] + stepSize RandomPoint[Circle[]]}]

Here is a method to simulate a lot of random walks dynamically.  This is the base case:
Method 1:
DynamicModule[
 {go = False, size = 1/2,
  walks = ConstantArray[{{0, 0}}, 256], 
  graphic = Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
 Column[
  {
   Row[{"Go", Checkbox[Dynamic[go]]}],
   Row[{"step size", Slider[Dynamic[size], {1/2, 2}]}],
   Dynamic[Dimensions[walks]],
   Dynamic[
    If[go, walks = grow[#, size] & /@ walks; 
     graphic = Graphics[Line /@ walks],
     graphic]]
   }
  ]
 ]

Above the "largish" and getting larger data is localized within a DynamicModule.  I guess there is a lot of overhead being placed in the FrontEnd and the WSTP?   The Checkbox for the Dynamic variable go and slider for size become unresponsive as the data set becomes larger.
Here is a simple fix to make the controls more responsive using Refresh:
Method 2
DynamicModule[{go = False, size = 1/2, 
  walks = ConstantArray[{{0, 0}}, 256], 
  graphic = Graphics[Rectangle[]]},
 Column[
  {
   Row[{"Go", Checkbox[Dynamic[go]]}],
   Row[{"step size", Slider[Dynamic[size], {1/2, 2}]}],
   Dynamic[Dimensions[walks]],
   Dynamic[
    If[go, Refresh[walks = grow[#, size] & /@ walks; 
      graphic = Graphics[Line /@ walks], UpdateInterval -> .5, 
      TrackedSymbols :> {}],
     graphic]]
   }
  ]
 ]

The controls become responsive, but I'm still worried about the overhead of maintaining the large Dynamic data even though all I want is the image.
Belowho, I wanted the computation to proceed and have the graphic updated at a different interval. I thought that using TrackedSymbols :> Automatic and UpdateInterval -> 100 would make the graphic update slowly, but have the computation proceed, but that didn't work. I am not sure why:
Method 3
DynamicModule[{go = False, size = 1/2, 
  graphic = Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
  walks = ConstantArray[{{0, 0}}, 256]},
 Column[
  {
   Row[{"Go", Checkbox[Dynamic[go]]}],
   Row[{"step size", Slider[Dynamic[size], {1/2, 2}]}],
   Dynamic[
    If[go, walks = grow[#, size] & /@ walks; 
     graphic = Graphics[Line /@ walks]]; Dynamic[Dimensions[walks]]],
   Dynamic[
    If[go, Refresh[graphic, TrackedSymbols :> Automatic, 
      UpdateInterval -> 100], graphic]]
   }
  ]
 ]

Now, I hope to improve performance and reduce overhead by not localizing the large-and-dynamic data.  Here I wrap Module around everything.
Method 4
Module[{walks = ConstantArray[{{0, 0}}, 256]},
 DynamicModule[{go = False, size = 1},
  Column[
   {
    Row[{"Go", Checkbox[Dynamic[go]]}],
    Row[{"step size", Slider[Dynamic[size], {1/2, 2}]}],
    Dynamic[
     If[go, Refresh[walks = grow[#, size] & /@ walks; 
       Dynamic[Dimensions[walks]]]]], 
    Dynamic[If[go, 
      Refresh[Graphics[Line /@ walks], UpdateInterval -> 2, 
       TrackedSymbols :> {}]]],
    
    }
   ]
  ]
 ]

This does everything well and appears to be efficient.  But, the variable walks is highlighted in red with a mouseover tip about "not being evaluated before going out of scape", which I don't understand but would like to.  I am worried that this method---which seems like good solution to me---is not robust or advisable.

Is there a solution that doesn't get the syntax warning?
Am I correct that avoiding the WSTP overhead by not localizing my data more efficient?

If you include the definition of grow it would make it easier to test. General comment is that the best way to see why you need to use DynamicModule is to close and open your notebook with and without it.

@MikeHoneychurch, It’s up there, but perhaps you missed it. Just below the bold words “Proxy Problem”.  Thanks for taking a look.

@MikeHoneychurch, I've edited to make the function definition more salient.  I think I understand the persistence of variables between kernels in DynamicModule.  Do you think this is a reasonable work-around: draw[data_ /; NumericQ[Flatten[data][[1]]]] := Graphics[<....>] in the Initialization option. That is, if the data is not "drawable", then just return something that displays something to display quickly.

OK, I tried that hack. It kind of works between different instances of the kernel.  But, I get weird behavior I don't understand. If the trigger is clicked once, I get an example that I recognize from the documentation!.  Clicking it a second time gives me the expected output.  I'm flummoxed.

It is important to remember that Module variables are only valid during the evaluation of said Module.  Dynamic and DynamicModule do not evaluate at the same time (aka they have HoldFirst/HoldAll set) and are evaluated much later, when the FrontEnd requires the result.  Seeing that this is rarely the intended behavior, it is colored as red.

The solution I implemented in this case was to make a local copy of the walks variable as follows:
grow[positions_List, stepSize_] := 
Join[positions, {Last[positions] + stepSize  RandomPoint[Circle[]]}]

Module[{walks = ConstantArray[{{0, 0}}, 256]}, 
 DynamicModule[{go = False, size = 1, walks2 = walks}, 
  Column[{Row[{"Step size", Slider[Dynamic[size], {1/2, 2}]}], 
  Button["Start/Stop", go = ! go, Method -> "Queued" , 
  ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center], 
  Dynamic[If[go, walks2 = grow[#, size] & /@ walks2;
  Dimensions[walks2], "Paused" ]], 
  Dynamic[If[go, Graphics[Line /@ walks2], Graphics[{}] ], 
  UpdateInterval -> 2, TrackedSymbols :> {walks2, go}]}]]]

The main problem with using walks directly as a variable in DynamicModule is that when the walks variable is modified within a dynamic context, it conflicts with DynamicModule's internal mechanism, which tracks changes to its variables. Since walks were initially defined as a variable outside DynamicModule, Mathematica has difficulty properly tracking updates, leading to unexpected behavior such as an error or a possible error showing this with a redlining syntax.
By creating a local copy walks2 = walks inside DynamicModule, it is possible to effectively separate the dynamic part (walks2) from the static original (walks). This isolation ensures that Mathematica can safely handle the updates within walks2, without interfering with the external definition of walks.
Finally, using a Button instead of a CheckBox provides more control and reduces potential issues caused by rapid or continuous updates.

Note: The variable walks2 is localized within DynamicModule, which minimizes unnecessary data transfer to the kernel via WSTP. This means that computations on walks2 happen locally, reducing overhead and keeping execution times consistent. The function grow is likely optimized for local operations, allowing it to perform efficiently regardless of the data size.

That works.  Thanks, @E. Chan-López.  I don't understand if walks2 is being passed to the kernel via WSTP.  If it is, then why isn't the computation time taking a hit.  (It doesn't I monitored the timing of walks2 = grow[#, size] & /@ walks2, It's constant.)

@CraigCarter It's a pleasure to help! :-)

I edited the comment. It now has a question. If you have the time, can you take a look?

See the update, please! :-)

Thanks. That clarifies it.
